# `xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)` when running `startx`, but why?

Tags: xorg

Here is the log:

```
[ 43368.158] X.Org X Server 1.21.1.3
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 43368.158] Current Operating System: Linux housesparrow 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 x86_64
[ 43368.158] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=37507205-bfd0-40ee-8c7b-9d2f17d9f6ac ro
[ 43368.158] xorg-server 2:21.1.3-2ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 43368.158] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[ 43368.158]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 43368.158] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 43368.158] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jul  5 18:50:49 2022
[ 43368.158] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 43368.158] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 43368.158] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 43368.158] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 43368.158] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 43368.158] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 43368.158] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 43368.158] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 43368.158] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 43368.158] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 43368.158] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 43368.158] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 43368.158]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 43368.158] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 43368.158]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 43368.158] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 43368.158]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 43368.158] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 43368.158]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 43368.158] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 43368.158]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 43368.158] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[ 43368.158] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 43368.158] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 43368.158] (II) Loader magic: 0x55bf16b2b020
[ 43368.158] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 43368.158]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 43368.158]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[ 43368.158]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[ 43368.158]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 43368.159] (--) using VT number 2
 
[ 43368.159] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 43368.159] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 43368.159] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[ 43368.160] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:9bc8:103c:8767 rev 3, Mem @ 0xb0000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 43368.160] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 43368.160] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 43368.160] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.160]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.0
[ 43368.160]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 43368.160] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 43368.160] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 43368.160] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 43368.160] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[ 43368.160] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[ 43368.160] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[ 43368.161] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.161]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.21.1
[ 43368.161]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 43368.161]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 43368.161] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[ 43368.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 43368.161] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.161]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[ 43368.161]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 43368.161]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 43368.161] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[ 43368.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 43368.161] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.161]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[ 43368.161]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 43368.161]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 43368.161] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[ 43368.161] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[ 43368.161] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[ 43368.161] xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
[ 43368.161] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[ 43368.161] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[ 43368.161] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[ 43368.161] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 43368.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[ 43368.161] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.161]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.0.2
[ 43368.161]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[ 43368.161] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[ 43368.161] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 43368.161] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 43368.161] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[ 43368.161] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 43368.161] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[ 43368.161] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[ 43368.161] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[ 43368.164] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.164]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.1
[ 43368.164]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[ 43368.182] (II) modeset(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CML GT2)
[ 43368.182] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[ 43368.182] (==) modeset(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
[ 43368.182] (==) modeset(0): AsyncFlipSecondaries: disabled
[ 43368.193] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 has no monitor section
[ 43368.193] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[ 43368.205] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output HDMI-1
[ 43368.205] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[ 43368.205] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[ 43368.205] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[ 43368.205] (WW) modeset(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[ 43368.205] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[ 43368.205] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[ 43368.205] (WW) modeset(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
[ 43368.205] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 43368.205] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 43368.205] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[ 43368.205] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[ 43368.205] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[ 43368.205] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[ 43368.205] (II) Unloading fbdev
[ 43368.205] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[ 43368.205] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[ 43368.205] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[ 43368.205] (II) Unloading vesa
[ 43368.211] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[ 43368.211] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 43368.212] (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[ 43368.212] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[ 43368.212] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 43368.212] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: iris
[ 43368.212] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[ 43368.212] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension Present
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[ 43368.213] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[ 43368.213] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[ 43368.218] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized iris
[ 43368.218] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[ 43368.218] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[ 43368.218] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[ 43368.218] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[ 43368.218] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[ 43368.218] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[ 43368.239] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[ 43368.239] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 43368.239] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[ 43368.239] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[ 43368.240] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 43368.240]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.2.1
[ 43368.240]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 43368.240]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[ 43368.240] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[ 43368.240] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 43368.240] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[ 43368.241] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.241] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.241] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[ 43368.251] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[ 43368.251] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[ 43368.251] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 43368.251] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 43368.251] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "dvorak-intl"
[ 43368.262] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.262] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.262] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[ 43368.262] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 43368.262] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[ 43368.262] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[ 43368.262] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[ 43368.263] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.263] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.263] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
[ 43368.319] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3/event3"
[ 43368.319] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[ 43368.319] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 43368.319] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 43368.319] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "dvorak-intl"
[ 43368.321] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.321] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.323] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[ 43368.323] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 43368.323] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[ 43368.323] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 43368.323] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[ 43368.325] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.325] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.325] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[ 43368.343] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[ 43368.343] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[ 43368.343] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 43368.343] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 43368.343] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "dvorak-intl"
[ 43368.345] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.345] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.347] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
[ 43368.347] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 43368.347] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[ 43368.347] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[ 43368.347] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[ 43368.348] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.349] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.349] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
[ 43368.375] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0/event0"
[ 43368.375] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[ 43368.375] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 43368.375] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 43368.375] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "dvorak-intl"
[ 43368.377] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 43368.377] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.379] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[ 43368.379] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.379] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.380] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[ 43368.380] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.380] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.381] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event12)
[ 43368.381] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.381] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.382] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event13)
[ 43368.382] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.382] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.383] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event14)
[ 43368.383] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.383] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.384] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[ 43368.384] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.384] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.385] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[ 43368.385] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.385] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.385] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event7)
[ 43368.386] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.386] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.386] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event8)
[ 43368.386] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.386] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.387] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[ 43368.387] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 43368.387] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 43368.393] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HP WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event4)
[ 43368.393] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 43368.393] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'HP WMI hotkeys'
[ 43368.393] (**) HP WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[ 43368.393] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[ 43368.395] (II) event4  - HP WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[ 43368.395] (II) event4  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[ 43368.395] (II) event4  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
[ 43368.439] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input4/event4"
[ 43368.439] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[ 43368.439] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[ 43368.439] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 43368.439] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "dvorak-intl"
[ 43368.441] (II) event4  - HP WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[ 43368.441] (II) event4  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
```

There is no other error in the terminal. My server is a repurposed Desktop computer that used to work fine.

I ran `startx` as root on Ubuntu 22.

Comment: what happened exactly? What is the question?

Comment: Edit your question and add context and details. It's not clear what you're asking. Start by telling us what version of Ubuntu you are using. Tell us what you're trying to do. Explain what you actually did and provide the detailed results of your actions. Finally, so that we are clear what you're asking, you can try putting your question in the form of a question. Then before submitting, reread the question and ask yourself if you added enough details that someone might be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Nmath: This most probably concerns Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel version 5.15.0-39-generic) based on the version of Xorg X server. The question is "what caused the informational log entry "xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)" beyond what the message itself already spells out.