# How to remove splash screen on both startup and shutdown in Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: shutdown, startup, mate, plymouth

I just did a fresh install of Mate 22.04. I want to completely remove all splash screens for both startup and logout+shutdown.

There are plenty of questions and posts that describe how to do this for startup (e.g. [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/248/89062)), but none seemed to stop the splash screens on shutdown (for me at least). How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

## Edit 2:

Perhaps others can corroborate: are the steps described [here](https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-the-plymouth-boot-screen-in-ubuntu-20-04/) supposed to remove the **shutdown** splash as well as the startup splash? For some reason it did not remove the shutdown splash for me, but perhaps I did something wrong?

## Edit 1:

I tried [removing plymouth per these instructions](https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-the-plymouth-boot-screen-in-ubuntu-20-04/). It did remove the splash screens, but the system now no longer automatically logs in. I can log in at the text terminal, but `startx` doesn't work anymore. Help!

- The error with `startx` is vaguely similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417376/xf86enableio-failed-to-enable-i-o-ports-0000-03ff-operation-not-permitted-w), which has no answer.
- [These steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/151226/89062) to repair Xorg didn't work.

What has worked is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`; This also pulled down the `plymouth` package(s) I'd remove per that other links suggestion.

I do *not* know why, but at this point I have no splash screens on startup or shutdown, so I'm happy. I *do_not* recommend this chaotic approach to anyone else, so perhaps I'll await more official answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it removed the startup splash but not the logout splash, which is why I thought I'd ask. I'm not sure though, I tend to make a lot of mistakes with these commands, perhaps I did something wrong.